# Find pattern in every line with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have the following string

```
def name1
 toSomething

def name2 
  toSomethingElse
```

How could I find `name1` and `name2`.

Using `string.match(/(?:def) (.*)/)` gives me:

```
name1
 toSomething

def name2 
  toSomethingElse
```

So how can I search the string line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

`/(?:def)\s+([^\s]+)/g`

In the first group you will have what you need (`name1`, etc).

See here: http://regex101.com/r/rH0yH8

An example of how to run it:

```
var s = "def name1\ntoSomething\n\ndef name2 \ntoSomethingElse"
var re = /(?:def)\s+([^\s]+)/g

while (x = re.exec(s)) {
    alert(x[1])
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns `["def name1", "def name2"]` http://jsbin.com/ayodok/1/

Comment: @AndreasKöberle the 1st group of the match will give you what you need. Once you have the match, just do `match[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^def (.*)/gm
```

will do it.  The `g` flag matches every instance, and the `m` flag causes the `^` to match at the beginning of a line instead of at the beginning of the input only.

With `.exec`, you can loop and get the results one at a time.

```
var myString = 'def foo\n  boo\n\ndef bar\n  far\n';
for (var re = /^def (.*)/gm, match; (match = re.exec(myString));) {
  alert(match[1]);
}
```

or you can use `.match` on the string to get all of the results in one array, but that doesn't give you the capturing groups.

```
var myString = 'def foo\n  boo\n\ndef bar\n  far\n';
var re = /^def (.*)/gm;
var matches = myString.match(re);
```

Comment: @AndreasKöberle, the first one should give you the regular groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should just give you the match on the first line, since `.` does not match newlines.

That said, try `/(?:def)\s+(\S*)/`